# Consulta entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, select

Preciso fazer uma consulta da seguinte forma: selecionar um `jovem` que esteja na mesma `cidade` e `estado` que o `mentor` e que tenha o **maior número** de **características iguais** a do `mentor`.

Minha consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM jovem 
INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado 
WHERE jovem.jfaixaetaria = mentor.mfaixaetaria
  AND jovem.jescolaridade = mentor.mescolaridade 
  AND jovem.jhobby = mentor.mhobby 
  AND jovem.jcomida = mentor.mcomida 
  AND jovem.jmusica = mentor.mmusica 
  AND jovem.jesporte = mentor.mesporte 
  AND jovem.jtime = mentor.mtime 
  AND jovem.jcaracteristica = mentor.mcaracteristica 
  AND jovem.janimal = mentor.manimal 
  AND jovem.jlivro = mentor.mlivro 
  AND jovem.jsonho = mentor.msonho
```

Estrutura das tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já tentou fazer algo? posta o seu código pra tentarmos ajudar. (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Preciso adicionar o COUNT nos campos, os 2 que tiver mais combinações iguais será selecionado.

Comment: blz, agora qual o problema com essa sua consulta? erro? retorna coisa demais? não retorna nada?

Comment: Ele não dá erro... retorna o "jovem" que tem as respostas "iguais" ao do mentor... mas eu preciso que ele faça um "COUNT" de: o jovem 1 teve 4 respostas iguais de algum tutor - o jovem 2 teve 5 respostas iguais ao tutor...

Comment: ele retorna o `jovem` igual porque sua consulta só traz se todas as características forem iguais. mas você quer o que tenha mais características em comum, é isso? No caso das 11 possíveis (sem contar cidade e estado) você quer saber quem tem mais (tipo jovem_1 tem 6 iguais com monitor_1, jovem_2 tem 3 iguais com monitor_2).. é isso?

Comment: é isso mesmo! Só mudaria para: jovem_1 tem 6 iguais com monitor_1, jovem_2 tem 3 iguais com monitor_1)

Comment: O que são essas características? as colunas de cada tabela(todas) ou tem algumas que não devem ser comparada como e-mail e nome?

Comment: Nome, email, foto não precisam ser comparados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira que você pode fazer para atingir o resultado é comparar as colunas e com `CASE WHEN` retornando `1` para valores iguais e `0` para diferentes, no final basta somar o retorno de cada comparação, segue exemplo abaixo.

*Obs: Coloquei somente 2 comparações pois não sei quais são as caracteristicas(colunas) que você quer contar.*

```
SELECT 
  jnome AS jovem
  , mnome AS Mentor
  , (
    (CASE WHEN jfaixaetaria = mfaixaetaria THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN jescolaridade = mescolaridade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ) AS qtdCaracteristicasIguais
FROM ligacao
LEFT JOIN mentor ON ligacao.mentor = mentor.CPF
LEFT JOIN jovem ON ligacao.jovem = jovem.CPF
WHERE mcidade = jcidade
AND mestado   = jestado
```

Segue exemplo funcionando online:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4d41f/5)

Comment: Olá, Caique!

Teria como fazer esse código sem estar lincando com a tabela ligação? a minha tabela ligação não tem nada ainda...

Comment: Caique, fiz os testes aqui e deu certo! Porém eu tenho 9 "variáveis" iguais, mas aparece 17 na qtdCaracterisicasIguais...você sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Desculpa a demora a responder. Para que possamos te ajudar o ideal seria abrir uma nova pergunta. Inclua nela a query que você rodou, as tabelas envolvidas, o resultado obtido pela query e o resultado esperado. Com essas informações será possível simular seu ambiente.

Comment: Obrigada, Caique!

Consegui fazer funcionar

Answer (score 1):

**código não testado**

Não consegui testar aqui mas a ideia é a seguinte:

1. criar uma tabela temporária pra armazenar o que coincide entre cada `jovem` e `monitor` que moram na mesma cidade;
2. na consulta, somar o total de "coincidências"

Tenta fazer alguns testes, caso a lógica não esteja certa, a gente tenta arrumar.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabelaTemporaria AS (
    SELECT jovem.jid as 'jid', 
        mentor.mid as 'mid', 
        CASE jovem.jfaixaetaria WHEN mentor.mfaixaetaria THEN 1 else 0 end as 'faixaetaria',
        CASE jovem.jescolaridade WHEN mentor.mescolaridade THEN 1 else 0 end as 'escolaridade',
        CASE jovem.jhobby WHEN mentor.mhobby THEN 1 else 0 end as 'hobby',
        CASE jovem.jcomida WHEN mentor.mcomida THEN 1 else 0 end as 'comida',
        CASE jovem.jmusica WHEN mentor.mmusica THEN 1 else 0 end as 'musica',
        CASE jovem.jesporte WHEN mentor.mesporte THEN 1 else 0 end as 'esporte',
        CASE jovem.jtime WHEN mentor.mtime THEN 1 else 0 end as 'time',
        CASE jovem.jcaracteristica WHEN mentor.mcaracteristica THEN 1 else 0 end as 'caracteristica',
        CASE jovem.janimal WHEN mentor.manimal THEN 1 else 0 end as 'animal',
        CASE jovem.jlivro WHEN mentor.mlivro THEN 1 else 0 end as 'livro',
        CASE jovem.jsonho WHEN mentor.msonho THEN 1 else 0 end as 'sonho'
    FROM jovem INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado 
)

SELECT jid, mid, (faixaetaria + escolaridade + hobby + comida + musica + esporte + time + caracteristica + animal + livro + sonho) as total_caracteristicas
FROM tabelaTemporaria
ORDER BY total_caracteristicas DESC
--LIMIT 2 --LIMIT é opcional para o total que precisar de retornos
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!